# JProve $T_1$ is finite if there exists bijection from $T_1$ to another finite set $T_2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, self-learning

Let $T_1$ be non empty. Prove that $T_1$ is finite if there exists bijection from $T_1$ to another finite set $T_2$.

Now, we have $h : J_m \to T_1$

Assume another finite set $T_2$, so we have $h_1 : J_m \to T_2$.

Since both $h_1$ and $h_2$ are bijections, so is $h_1 \circ h^{-1}$

$J_m$ = ${\{1,2,3,...,m\}}$

Conversely, a similar idea can be used. But is this even correct?

Thanks

Comment: What definition of finite are you working with?

Comment: A set is finite if it has bijection from set of natural no's to that set